# Disjunctive Normal Form conversion

Tags: logic

Could someone show step by step how to convert the following formula into DNF ?

$$ (X \lor \neg Y ) \land (¬Z \lor \neg U \lor W) \land (S \lor \neg T) $$

Comment: What have you tried? How far did you get? Where do you get stuck? If you provide us so context we will have an easier time to help you understand and solve the problem.

Comment: Can you expand $(a+b)(c+d+e)(f+g)$ into a sum of products? What you need to do here is essentially the same thing, just with different symbols.

Comment: If you plan on participating in the Math.SE community, you may want to learn how to post mathematical expressions using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$(X \lor \lnot Y) \land (\lnot Z \lor \lnot U \lor W) \land (S \lor \lnot T)$$

You can use the distributive property to make the conversion: $(a \lor b) \land c = (a \lor c) \land (b \lor c)$.  Just pick one variable from each term.  Here are 3 examples:

$$(\color{red}{X} \lor \lnot Y) \land (\color{red}{\lnot Z} \lor \lnot U \lor W) \land (\color{red}{S} \lor \lnot T)$$

Contributes a term $(X \land \lnot Z \land S)$.

$$(X \lor \lnot \color{red}{Y}) \land (\lnot Z \lor \color{red}{\lnot U} \lor W) \land (S \lor \color{red}{\lnot T})$$

Contributes a term $(Y \land \lnot U \land \lnot T)$.

$$(\color{red}{X} \lor \lnot Y) \land (\lnot Z \lor \lnot U \color{red}{\lor W}) \land (S \lor \color{red}{\lnot T})$$

Contributes a term $(X \land W \land \lnot T)$.

There are 12 terms altogether in the final DJF.  It will be like:

$$(X \land \lnot Z \land S) \lor (Y \land \lnot U \land \lnot T) \lor (X \land W \land \lnot T) \lor \dots \text{9 more terms} \dots$$

Find the last 9 terms in the same way as the first 3 and you'll have it.